# ERROR: ResolutionImpossible error when deploying web application on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Update:

2022.05.08
I renamed the "requirement.txt" as "requirements.txt". But it cannot solve my problem. Now, new error information is

```
2022/05/08 03:30:45.608563 [INFO] ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 1), -r requirements.txt (line 7) and botocore==1.23.24 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

Here is more information

health cause:

```
ELB processes are not healthy on all instances.
None of the instances are sending data.
ELB health is failing or not available for all instances.
```

first 10 lines(requirements file), this file was created by the command "pip freeze > requirements.txt"

```
aiobotocore==2.1.1
aiohttp==3.8.1
aioitertools==0.10.0
aiosignal==1.2.0
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==21.4.0
boto3==1.21.10
botocore==1.23.24
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
```

so, the packages that cannot be installed are: "aiobotocore", "botocore", and "boto3".

It seems so wired. "boto3" is a Python SDK for AWS, why it cannot be supported by AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

---

I created a flask application to download files from S3. it worked well on my local PC, but I meet the 'Health: severe' problem when I tried to deploy my code on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I checked the log and find this:

```
May  8 01:28:48 ip-172-31-7-112 web: from flask import Flask, Response, render_template
May  8 01:28:48 ip-172-31-7-112 web: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
May  8 01:28:48 ip-172-31-7-112 web: [2022-05-08 01:28:48 +0000] [4977] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 4977)
May  8 01:28:48 ip-172-31-7-112 web: [2022-05-08 01:28:48 +0000] [4971] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
May  8 01:28:48 ip-172-31-7-112 web: [2022-05-08 01:28:48 +0000] [4971] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
May  8 01:28:49 ip-172-31-7-112 web: [2022-05-08 01:28:49 +0000] [4985] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
May  8 01:28:49 ip-172-31-7-112 web: [2022-05-08 01:28:49 +0000] [4985] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (4985)
May  8 01:28:49 ip-172-31-7-112 web: [2022-05-08 01:28:49 +0000] [4985] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
May  8 01:28:49 ip-172-31-7-112 web: [2022-05-08 01:28:49 +0000] [4991] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4991
May  8 01:28:49 ip-172-31-7-112 web: [2022-05-08 01:28:49 +0000] [4991] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
```

I'm sure my application file is named as "application.py" and the application also is named as "application"

```
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template
from boto3 import client

application = Flask(__name__)

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(debug=True)
```

I also checked the requirement.txt and find the flask information

```
Flask==2.0.3
flask==2.0.3 # at first I think it is an uppercase/lowercase issue, so I add the 'flask==2.0.3'
```

My python.config file:

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: application:application
```

Comment: _I also checked the requirement.txt_ Usually this filename is spelled `requirements.txt`, with an `s`.  Perhaps that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question and now I solve it, so I want to share how I address this problem.

First, I tried to fix this error by adjusting the package's version because the log provides more details about this issue like this:

```
The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested botocore==1.25.9
    aiobotocore 2.3.1 depends on botocore<1.24.22 and >=1.24.21
```

However, it doesn't work. Each time I adjust the version, a new package dependency issue arises.

So, I uninstalled all packages on Pycharm and install them one by one to make sure my application can run on my local PC. Next, I create a new 'requirements.txt' file by command

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then, I zip all the needed files and deploy my application on AWS. It works! The health status is OK.